# My UV texture works in the texture paint window, but not in any other window

Tags: texturing, uv, image, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

[image: broken texture]I have recently textured a dragon model in blender, but when I set up all the nodes and change the view to material preview in another mode, the image texture doesn't texture the model correctly. I think the UV map is messed up or something but I don't know how to fix it. I included screenshots of the texture paint window (working texture) and the motion tracking window (broken texture)[[image: correct texturebroken texture]

Comment: Does your model have more than one UV map? If you do have that, you can check the one that lines up with your paint scheme and correct the alignment that way.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I figured out how to fix it :)